# Setup EF core to not create Database Foreign Key for specific Navigation Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Consider entities `Company` and `Product`:

```cs
public class Company
{
    prop Guid Id {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    prop Guid CompanyId {get; set;}
    prop Company Company {get; set;}
}
```

When creating migrations, I want the relationship from `Product` to `Company` not to create a foreign key constraint in the database.

I understand all the problems with not creating foreign keys, I always create foreign keys, but in one specific problem, I want to avoid one foreign key. How to do that?

Explanation: This is some diagnostics data, so I need to keep all the info that can help diagnostics, even when the main entity cannot be inserted.
If that is inserted, we'll be happy to use Navigation properties to navigate to it. If it fails, we can go back to the original source of data and see what is wrong with this specific `Company`

Comment: How about make it nullable, will it work in your case?

Comment: Note that in 2.2.6 if you then anvigate this in efcore it will not work of the related object is not there (i.e. company is deleted). This is a known bug that also happens to make global query filters totally unusable (because it will ALSO bug out if a filter is added there that removes the company). This is fixed in 3.0 and later.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus no, this won't help. Please See the added explanation

Comment: How about just remove the `prop Company Company`, only save the id, then when accessing the company, just load it manually using EF with join.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus I've already used that workaround mechanism. I like to know if there exists any actual solution, to be able to keep all features of EF like navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the created ForeignKey codes which are created by EF. And then do the migration action.
Hope this will help you. Eg: (some lines like below)

```
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Products_Companies_CompanyId",
                    column: x => x.CompanyId,
                    principalTable: "Companies",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that One needs to remember this for all the future migrations they create on the same DbContext. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: It worked, but on next "add-migration" actions, it still tries to create the Foreign Key. How to avoid that ?

Comment: Aah, so simple! With EF Core 3.1 on a subsequent migration I don't see the FK being created - so this really does the trick!